# Night watch body on load

Tags: nightwatch.js

How do we use night watch to check it the browser has finished loading the page?

I currently use waitForElementVisible('body')

Is there a way to check using nightwatch maybe by using the execute function if a page is fully loaded

Comment: Why not use body.onload=...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just check `document.readyState` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

`browser.execute("return document.readyState;", function(result) {
    if (result.value === "complete") {
        // document is completely initialized.
    } else if (result.value === "interactive") {
        // User can interact with the document even though it is not fully loaded.
    } else {
        // it's still loading
    }
});`